# will too much extension methods degrads performance ? how it works

Tags: c#, .net, performance, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I m a great fan of csharp 4..
i have added too much methods to **string object (.net types)** as an extension method
consider approximately 200
will that degrads performance?

is it right to add these much methods in **.nets library** ?
how actually extension methods work internally..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, It is not going to affect runtime performance anyway. Since "Extension Methods" are just compiler trick. Under the hood they are  just a static methods in a static class.

```
public static class MyExt
{
    public static void MyExtension(this object obj)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}    
public static void Main()
{
    object obj = new object();
    obj.MyExtension();
    //Above line gets compiled into MyExt.MyExtension(obj);
}
```

As you can see `obj.MyExtension();` gets compiled into `MyExt.MyExtension(obj);` and it is just a method call only. *No need of worrying about performance*.

If at all you're worried about performance I'd say it won't hurt "runtime performance" though it may or may not hurt compile time performance, Compiler needs to find whether any extension method defined in current namespace as well as imported namespaces.

That is not going to be hard though, since compiler needs to check only `static` classes. No library is going to have numerous "static classes".

Comment: is it fine from coding/design perspective to add these much methods to .net primitive types like string,int,long etc..  ?

Comment: @vishalsharma Operator bloat can be controlled by distributing the extension methods into appropriate namespaces and importing those namespaces selectively. But if you are using primitive types a lot, you might be suffering from [primitive obsession](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/PrimitiveObsession.html).

Comment: @vishalsharma Based on the method purpose you can group it in different namespaces. Nothing wrong in having number of methods. but don't declare those methods for `System.Object` to use it with `int` `float` In that case use `T` generic type to avoid boxing

Answer (score 0):

There are no performance penalties for using extension methods, however there is such a thing as bad extension method design. There is a great article about the do's and don'ts of extension methods here: [The DOS and DONTS of extension methods.](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1217/the-dos-and-don-ts-of-extension-methods)

Comment: is it fine from coding/design perspective to add these much methods to .net primitive types like string,int,long etc..  ?